# Webwervice security header in java client code

Tags: java, web-services

```
<soapenv:Header>
<UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">uname</UsernameToken>
<PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">pass</PasswordText>
<SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have generated client code using axis runtime and I am getting this exception:Operation 'QueryByExample' with no authentication cannot be executed in an anonymous session pool. Please associate an authentication type with the web service operation.(SBL-EAI-04552).

I looked at others answers from stackoverflow for hours and nothing worked out for me. Please guide me....

Service code:

```
SOAPHeaderElement wsseSecurity = new SOAPHeaderElement(new PrefixedQName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext","Security", "wsse"));
        MessageElement username = new MessageElement("uname", "UsernameToken");
        MessageElement password = new MessageElement("pass", "PasswordText");
        username.setObjectValue("username");
        password.setObjectValue("password");
        wsseSecurity.addChild(username);
        wsseSecurity.addChild(password);
stub.setHeader(wsseSecurity);
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error you are getting from the log. Maybe few lines before and few lings after where the error happens would definitely help too.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Operation 'QueryByExample_1' with no authentication cannot be executed in an anonymous session pool. Please associate an authentication type with the web service operation.(SBL-EAI-04552)
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://www.siebel.com/ws/fault}siebdetail:<

Operation 'QueryByExample_1' with no authentication cannot be executed in an anonymous session pool. Please associate an authentication type with the web service operation.(SBL-EAI-04552)

Comment: great thanks, are you using Siebel Server ?

Comment: I am using weblogic server for deployment and I am consuming webservices here... I think they are using Siebel server.

Comment: can somebody look at this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few more things and the main problem is how you are deifning and using your password. You are on the correct path but here is how you would make a  SOAP Axis 1.4 client:

```
InputStream inConfig = BaseTestCase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("axis_client_config.xml");
        EngineConfiguration config = new FileProvider(inConfig);
        PartnerAPILocator locator = new PartnerAPILocator(config);
        inConfig.close();

        stub = locator.getSoap();

        Stub axisPort = (Stub) stub;
        axisPort._setProperty(UsernameToken.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
        axisPort._setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "ET USERNAME");
        axisPort._setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new PasswordTokenHandler());
```

here is my [source](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_java_and_axis_14/) and try to follow the tutorial and you can even download the code. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks.. What is the BAseTestCase.class where to get that

Comment: welcome, would you also give it a 1+ for my answer above please, if you find it useful . you can download all the those classes at http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_java_and_axis_14/ it's a zip file in the middle of the page.